# How to make a navbar extend left on click? [Twitter bootstrap 3]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar in twitter bootstrap that will extent to the left when clicked.

like the navbar at the top of www.ebuyer.co.uk

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="height:50px; float:top">
```

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li style="width:300px; margin-top:7px">
        <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seach for a movie..." style="margin-right:20px">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:10px" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
         </span>   
       </div>
      </li>

     <li style="margin-top:-7px"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button></a></li>

</ul>
```

The text input with the placeholder "Search for a movie" is the inputbox i will me modifying. I would like to make it extend to the left in a smooth animation changing from width:250px to width:400px.

Is anyone able to help me out as i have no clue how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: use animation via jQuery http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Do you want the entire navbar to extend to the left or simply the input box for text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to do that. If you use jquery you can animate the input or the element you want, like this:

Simple HTML

```
<input type="search"/>
```

Simple CSS

```
input {width: 100px;}
```

And finally a basic jquery function

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: '200px'
    },100); // Time of the animation in milliseconds
}).on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '100px'
    },100); // Time of the animation in milliseconds
});
```

I put the code in a jsfiddle so you can see the example in action [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/Z9a3P/)

Comment: Thats great but it still extends to the right how do i make it extent to the left?

Comment: In the example newpatriks provided the input horizontal position is fixed by `right: 120px`, so it extends to the left. If you fix your input position from the left, it will extend to the right.